# jQuery addClass to parent divs only, in a numbered fashion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can only seem to number all divs within the relative element, or in the singular only, is there a way exclude the children like this while transforming the classes into an pseudo ol?

```
<div id="parent_relative_div_no_addclass">
      **<div class"blah_addclass1">**
            <div class="do_not_addclass"></div>
                   <div class="do_not_addclass"></div>
            <div class="do_not_addclass"></div>
            <div class="do_not_addclass"></div>
      </div>
      **<div class"blah_addclass2">**
            <div class="do_not_addclass"></div>
            <div class="do_not_addclass"></div>
            <div class="do_not_addclass"></div>
      </div>
      **<div class"blah_addclass3">**
            <div class="do_not_addclass"></div>
            <div class="do_not_addclass"></div>
            <div class="do_not_addclass"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Any input appreciated, Thankyou

William

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#parent_relative_div_no_addclass').children().each(function(i) {
  $(this).addClass('blah_addclass'+i);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach works, using the CSS direct-descendant operator `>`:

```
$('#parent_relative_div_no_addclass > div').each(
    function(i) {
        $(this).addClass('blah_addclass_' + i);
    });
```